# Both 5V pins are taken but I need more

Tags: power, sensor, breadboard, connectors

Hi I am doing a project where both 5V pins are taken by a step down connected to a solar panel.
I am using a raspberry 3B and a breadboard.

I need 5V to connect other stuff like ultrasonic sensor etc. What can I do.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attaching one of the 5V pins to whatever it is attached to, connect it to an empty channel on the breadboard.  You can then connect whatever needs power to this channel.

Breadboards commonly have two channels **perpendicular** to the main columns running the whole length of both long sides, as below. These are called *rails*, and the shorter columns making up the bulk of the board are *terminals*.  If your breadboard does not have such rails, you can use a normal terminal column instead.

[image]

Notice the red and blue lines. These can be used to indicate power and ground.  The point is you connect a power source to the red channel and ground to the blue one, then use any of the remaining holes in the long rail to connect whatever needs power.

You can use both sides if you want, eg., a 3.3V rail and a 5V rail.

*Make sure you understand the horizontal and vertical continuity of the terminals and rails when you do this.*  You can easily create a short circuit by connecting the wrong things together.

Comment: Also make sure that you have sufficient power available through the 5V pins and the current draw does not exceed the rating of either the 5V pin, nor the breadboard rail